# gcc auto vectorization control flow in loop

Tags: c, gcc, avx2, auto-vectorization

In the code below, why is the second loop able to be auto vectorized but the first cannot?  How can I modify the code so it does auto vectorize?  gcc says:

> note: not vectorized: control flow in loop.

I am using gcc 8.2, flags are -O3 -fopt-info-vec-all.  I am compiling for x86-64 avx2.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void foo(const float * x, const float * y, const int * v, float * vec, float * novec, size_t size) {
    size_t i;
    float bar;
    for (i=0 ; i<size ; ++i){
        bar = x[i] - y[i];
        novec[i] = v[i] ? bar : NAN;
    }
    for (i=0 ; i<size ; ++i){
        bar = x[i];
        vec[i] = v[i] ? bar : NAN;
    }
}
```

Update:
This does autovectorize:

```
for (i=0 ; i<size ; ++i){
    bar = x[i];
    novec[i] = v[i] ? bar : NAN;
    novec[i] -= y[i];
}
```

I would still like to know why gcc says control flow for the first loop.

Comment: Vectorizes for me.

Comment: @EOF: clang vectorizes it the way you'd expect, but gcc8.2 doesn't.  (Even with `restrict` added to all the pointers, and with `-march=haswell`)  https://godbolt.org/z/cnlwuO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

clang auto-vectorizes even the first loop, but gcc8.2 doesn't.  (https://godbolt.org/z/cnlwuO)

gcc vectorizes with `-ffast-math`.  Perhaps it's worried about preserving FP exception flag status from the subtraction?

**`-fno-trapping-math` is sufficient for gcc to auto-vectorize (without the rest of what `-ffast-math` sets), so apparently it's worried about FP exceptions**.  (https://godbolt.org/z/804ykV).  I think it's being over-cautious, because the C source *does* compute `bar` every time, whether or not it's used.

gcc will auto-vectorize simple FP `a[i] = b[i]+c[i]` loops without any FP math options.

Comment: (GCC's default of `-ftrapping-math` is buggy the other way as well: sometimes it *will* compute stuff the C source doesn't, potentially raising FP exceptions the source wouldn't have.  So it's just broken, and has been for a long time.  I'd recommend `-fno-trapping-math` as part of your standard options,  Along with `-fno-math-errno`, and `-O3 -march=native`.)